# ListAsGridBaseAdapter only displays grid items when there are even number of items

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter, listadapter

I have been using plattysoft's [ListAsGridBaseAdapter](https://github.com/plattysoft/grid-with-header-list-adapter/blob/master/ListAsGridAdapter/src/com/plattysoft/ui/ListAsGridBaseAdapter.java) to display gridview items with a scrollable header on top. My gridview has 2 columns and when I have an odd number of items (like 1 item) to display, nothing comes up on the gridview, only the header is shown. The items are only shown when there are an even number of items (like 2 or 4 items).

I've been trying to debug this for awhile and can't figure out what in the [code](https://github.com/plattysoft/grid-with-header-list-adapter/blob/master/ListAsGridAdapter/src/com/plattysoft/ui/ListAsGridBaseAdapter.java) linked is causing this.

EDIT: The grid does not show the n-th odd elements for 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 gridview items. If you have 10 or more gridview items then it displays all of the items.

The edited version of ListAsGridExampleAdapter.java is below:

```
public class ListAsGridExampleAdapter extends ListAsGridBaseAdapter {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public ListAsGridAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("item 1/5", "item", R.drawable.item_pic, 0, 0));
        items.add(new Item("item 2/5", "item", R.drawable.item_pic, 0, 0));
        items.add(new Item("item 3/5", "item", R.drawable.item_pic, 0, 0));
        items.add(new Item("item 4/5", "item", R.drawable.item_pic, 0, 0));
        items.add(new Item("item 5/5", "item", R.drawable.item_pic, 0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected View getItemView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View item = view;
        if (view == null) {         
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, viewGroup, false);
            item.setTag(R.id.item_icon, item.findViewById(R.id.item_icon));
            item.setTag(R.id.item_title, item.findViewById(R.id.item_title));
        }
        Item currentItem = (Item)getItem(position);


        // Fill the view
        ImageView itemImage = (ImageView)item.getTag(R.id.item_icon);
        itemImage.setImageResource(currentItem.getIconID());

        // Item Name:
        TextView itemText = (TextView)item.getTag(R.id.item_title);
        itemText.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
        return item;
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of what is displayed, as you can see the 5th element is missing:
 [image: missing 5th item]

Comment: I actually tried that out when I developed it and it used to work, the even element should be displayed on its own row.

Comment: @shalafi do you mean the odd element? I narrowed down the bug to be in the createItemRow method.

Comment: yes, sorry, the odd element. I just checked it out, recompiled and it worked fine for me (see answer)
Also, if it is a bug, it's more handy to open an issue on github than asking here (at least for that I'll get a notification)

Comment: @shalafi I included a screenshot and a slightly different version of ListAsGridExampleAdapter above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: it turns out that inflating the view with the parent leads to this problem.
The current solution (workaround) is to inflate it passing a null parent.

So, this:

```
item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, viewGroup, false);
```

Should be:

```
item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
```

Yes, this is a bug and I'll try to fix it in the future. Thanks for finding it!

It works with more than 10 items because when you scroll, views are recycled by the adapter and therefore the parent has been appropriately measures.

Previous answer:

I just recompiled the last version of the sample, which has an odd number of items and it shows the last item on a separate row.

Maybe there is a bug with a specific configuration by number of columns / items, but in principle it works.

[image]

Comment: Can you try odd number items like 1, 3, or 5 items. I mentioned it in the edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I just tried it with 5 and it worked fine (2 columns)
Check out the sample project and see how it works for you.

Comment: I included a screenshot and a slightly different version of ListAsGridExampleAdapter above!

Comment: Ok, I inflated them with null as parent, maybe that has some impact (although the correct way of doing it is as you did)

Comment: So is there an issue in my modified ListAsGridExampleAdapter? or is it correct because I used it with your ListAsGridBaseAdapter.

Comment: In theory it is correct and it should work. I'd try passing a null parent to see if it solved the issue as it is the only difference.
If that is the case, I'll try to fix it so it works as it should.

Comment: That fixed it, do you know why?

Comment: I think the parent layout has 0 height at the time of inflating the children, so if you pass null, they will take no constrains, while if you use the parent, the height will be 0.

Comment: Anyway, that is a bug and I should fix it in the future